# Updating ListView to strikethough item on click

Tags: android, listview, adapter

I am using a CursorAdapter with a ListView and a cursor getting data from an sqlite database. I have this function called RenderList() which I call every time I update the database with a new item for the list or if I set the checked value of a row to one (this will add the new item or strikethough the item name).

```
private void renderList(){

    String showWhere = show_checked ? null : DbHelper.C_CHECKED + "= '0' ";

    try {

        db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        cursor = db.query(DbHelper.TABLE, null, showWhere, null, null, null, dbHelper.C_ID + " DESC");

        groceriesList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        adapter = new GroceryAdapter(this, cursor);
        adapter.newView(getApplicationContext(), cursor, groceriesList);            
        groceriesList.setAdapter(adapter);      
        groceriesList.setOnItemClickListener(itemListener);

     } catch (Exception e) {
         Log.d(TAG, "RenderList Error: ",e);
     }
}
```

This will reset the list, so if I click an item that is way down the listview it will reset the listview to the top position. Obviously I'm missing something with how to update the listview, and the database in an efficient, and usable way?

```
public class GroceryAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

    private final LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public GroceryAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor) {

      super(context, cursor, true);
      mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
     // mContext = context;

    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        TwoLineListItem listItem = (TwoLineListItem)view;
        TextView t1 = listItem.getText1();
        TextView t2 = listItem.getText2();

        t1.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.C_GROCERY)));
        t2.setText("Added by: Wes");

        t1.setTag(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.C_ID)));
        t2.setTag(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.C_CHECKED)));

        if (cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.C_CHECKED)) == 1 ) {
            t1.setPaintFlags(t1.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
            listItem.setBackgroundColor(0xEECCCCCC);
        } else {
            t1.setPaintFlags(t1.getPaintFlags() & (~Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG) );
            listItem.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        final View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.grocery_list_item, parent, false);
        return view;
    }

}
```

Comment: you can use adapter.notifydatasetchanged

Comment: Like Iftikar said-  notifyDataSetChanged.  That tells the adapter that the data has changed, and causes the listview to refresh itself completely.

Comment: I've tried notifyDataSetChanged and it doesn't seem to be updating the view. Do I need to add some sort of a listener/observer method in my CursorAdapter?